# Looping over tf.data.Dataset very slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm wondering why a for-loop over samples of a tf.data.Dataset is so much slower than looping over the corresponding numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time

a = np.ones(100000, dtype=np.float32)

start_time = time.time()
for x in a:
    pass
print(time.time() - start_time)

start_time = time.time()
for x in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a):
    pass
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

---

```
0.05548405647277832
5.67711615562439
```

My TensorFlow version is 2.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, even i have observed same behavior. To improve speed/performance try wrapping `tf.data.dataset` in a [@tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) and it will take almost the same time.

[AutoGraph](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#autograph_transformations) is on default in `tf.function` and transforms your Python eager code into graph-compatible TensorFlow ops. This includes control flow like `if`, `for`, `while`.

`tf.function` works best with TensorFlow ops, NumPy and Python calls are converted to constants.

Please refer code shown below to wrap within `@tf.function`

```
@tf.function

def oper(a):
    start_time = time.time()
    for x in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a):
        pass
    print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Complete working code shown below between `numpy` and `tf.data.dataset` performance

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import time

a = np.ones(100000, dtype=np.float32)

start_time = time.time()
for x in a:
    pass
print(time.time() - start_time)


@tf.function

def oper(a):
    start_time = time.time()

    for x in tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a):
        pass
    print(time.time() - start_time)

oper(a)
```

output:

```
0.012496232986450195
0.017792224884033203
```

To know more about `tf.function` please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function).

Comment: Isn't the print just executed when the function is traced?