# How can I create and shuffle a dataset for triplet mining in TensorFlow 2?

Tags: dataset, tensorflow2.0

I'm working on a network using triplet mining for training. In order to make it work properly, I need my batches to contain several images of the same class. The problem I'm currently facing is that I have 751 classes, for a total of 12,937 pictures, and a batch size of 48 pictures. When shuffling the dataset using the command below, the odds to get pictures from the same class are really low, making the triplet mining inefficient.

```py
dataset = dataset.shuffle(12937)
```

What I would need instead is a way of generating batches that contain a specific number of pictures for every class represented in this batch. As an example, let's say here that I want 12 classes per batch, there would be 4 pictures for each of them.

Another problem I'm facing is how would I shuffle this dataset at the end of every epoch so that I can have different batches that still follow the condition fixed above, that is 12 classes, 4 pictures for each one of them?

Is there any proper way to do it? I can't really find one. Please let me know if I'm unclear, and if you need further details.

================ EDIT ================

I've been trying a few things, and came up with something that would do what I want. The function would be the following:

```py
counter = 0.

# Assuming a format such as (data, label)
def predicate(data, label):
    global counter
    allowed_labels = tf.constant([counter])
    isallowed = tf.equal(allowed_labels, tf.cast(label, tf.float32))
    reduced = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(isallowed, tf.float32))
    counter += 1
    return tf.greater(reduced, tf.constant(0.))

#@tf.function
def custom_shuffle(train_dataset, batch_size, samples_per_class = 4, iterations_in_epoch = 100, database='market'):
    assert batch_size%samples_per_class==0, F'batch size must be a {samples_per_class} multiple.'
    if database == 'market':
        class_nbr = 751
    else:
        raise Exception('Unsuported database yet') 

    all_datasets = [train_dataset.filter(predicate) for _ in range(class_nbr)]  # Every element of this array is a dataset of one class

    for i in range(iterations_in_epoch):
        choice = tf.random.uniform(
            shape=(batch_size//samples_per_class,), 
            minval=0,
            maxval=class_nbr, 
            dtype=tf.dtypes.int64,
        )  # Which classes will be in batch
        choice = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.concat([choice for _ in range(4)], axis=0))  # Exactly 4 picture from each class in the batch
        batch = tf.data.experimental.choose_from_datasets(all_datasets, choice)
        if i==0:
            all_batches = batch
        else:
            all_batches = all_batches.concatenate(batch)
    all_batches = all_batches.batch(batch_size)
    return all_batches
```

It does what I want, however the returned dataset is extremely slow to iterate, making modele learning impossible. As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62453823/looping-over-tf-data-dataset-very-slow), I understood that I needed to decorate `custom_shuffle` with `@tf.function`, as the one commented out. However, when doing so, it raises the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "training.py", line 137, in <module>
    main()
  File "training.py", line 80, in main
    train_dataset = get_dataset(TRAINING_FILENAMES, IMG_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE, database=database, func_type='train')
  File "E:\Morgan\TransReID_TF\tfr_to_dataset.py", line 260, in get_dataset
    dataset = custom_shuffle(dataset, batch_size)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\AlignedReID_TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\AlignedReID_TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 846, in _call
    return self._concrete_stateful_fn._filtered_call(canon_args, canon_kwds)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\AlignedReID_TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1843, in _filtered_call
    return self._call_flat(
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\AlignedReID_TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 1923, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\AlignedReID_TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 545, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda3\envs\AlignedReID_TF\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError:  No unary variant device copy function found for direction: 1 and Variant type_index: class tensorflow::data::`anonymous namespace'::DatasetVariantWrapper
         [[{{node BatchDatasetV2/_206}}]] [Op:__inference_custom_shuffle_11485]

Function call stack:
custom_shuffle
```

Which I don't understand, and don't see how to fix.
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

PS: I'm aware the lack of minimal code to reproduce this behavior makes it hard to debug, I'll try to provide some as soon as possible.

Comment: Try to use `sample_from_datasets`. More information https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/sample_from_datasets

Comment: It doesn't quite fit my needs, but it made me look at tf.data.experimental function, which I hadn't think of, and thank you for that. `choose_from_datasets` would be more like it, but there are still more issues. I edited the post accordingly. Would you see what is wrong?